# SSD1351: Image corruption (Pi Pico SPI buffer issue)

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to get an SSD1351 driver working with a 128x128 OLED display, driven by a Raspberry Pi Pico. I have been able to get the statistics part of this working, however the image is being corrupted when I start a game and the statistics switch over to the combined image.

The script works by using a python script to send the RGB565 binary data over to the Pico RAM, and then pipes it into a buffer to be sent to the display. Firstly I am displaying a basic splashscreen video which works just fine, and switches over to the stats on detection of a COM port to the Pico. This part of the script works.

The part I am having trouble with is when I start a game, I am triggering the image to be sent on the screen after clearing the old statistics buffer. At the moment, the image is corrupt and not being displayed properly at all. I'm positive my python script is working just fine as I've confirmed it works on other hardware, so the problem has to be on the Pico side (either reading in the image data incorrectly or writing it to the display RAM incorrectly).

The statistics are displaying fine, however when starting a game and switching over to the combined image to be displayed on the screen, things start to go weird (image sometimes is shifted, other times it is pixelated) - the behaviour seems rather random which makes it hard to debug.

I have tried resending the SSD1351_CMD_SETCOLUMN and SSD1351_CMD_SETROW commands within the SSD1351_update() function whenever I refresh the display. I think some bytes were getting dropped during the transmission, causing the data to be written at a pixel offset - this fixed the statistics issue being off center, however the image corruption still remains.

I am reading the image data with getchar_timeout_us() over the serial interface.

**Pico Driver - SSD1351 (main.c)**

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/binary_info.h"
#include "pico/multicore.h"
#include "hardware/gpio.h"
#include "hardware/spi.h"
#include "ssd1351.h"
#include "splash_vid.h"

#define IMAGE_SIZE_BYTES 32768

extern uint8_t buffer[OLED_BUF_SIZE];

volatile  bool thread_running = false;

void play_splash_vid(void) {
  int t = 0;
    while(t < 20){
      SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
      SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[0], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
      sleep_ms(500);
      for (int f = 1; f < FRAME_COUNT; f++) {
      SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
      SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[f], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
      sleep_ms(10);
      }
      SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
      SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[0], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
      sleep_ms(500);

      t++;
    }
    SSD1351_fill(COLOR_WHITE);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(20, 64);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, "NO CONNECTION");
    SSD1351_update();
  }

void splash_vid_single(void) {
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[0], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
  sleep_ms(500);
  for (int f = 1; f < FRAME_COUNT; f++) {
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[f], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
  sleep_ms(10);
  }
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  SSD1351_write_data_buffer(frame[0], OLED_BUF_SIZE);
  sleep_ms(500);
  }

void display_image(void) {
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, buffer, OLED_BUF_SIZE);
  SSD1351_update();
}

void display_stats(void) {
  // Stats to read from Pi and show on OLED
  char SD_usage[1024];      // A
  char CPU_temp[1024];      // B
  char CLK_speed[1024];     // C
  char RAM_usage[1024];     // D
  char IP_addr[1024];       // E

  char prev_SD_usage[1024];      // A
  char prev_CPU_temp[1024];      // B
  char prev_CLK_speed[1024];     // C
  char prev_RAM_usage[1024];     // D
  char prev_IP_addr[1024];       // E

  // Buffer to hold data read over USB from Pi
  char stat_buf[1024];

  // Title colour
  int r = 255;
  int g = 255;
  int b = 255;

  // Value colour
  int r1 = 180;
  int g1 = 180;
  int b1 = 180;

  while(thread_running) {
    // Get Values
    
    int s = 0;
    while(s < 6){
      scanf("%16s", stat_buf);
      if (stat_buf[0] == 'S') {
        break;
      }
      else if (stat_buf[0] == 'A') {
        strncpy(SD_usage, stat_buf + 1, strlen(stat_buf));
        s++;
      }
      else if (stat_buf[0] == 'B') {
        strncpy(CPU_temp, stat_buf + 1, strlen(stat_buf));
        s++;
      }
      else if (stat_buf[0] == 'C') {
        strncpy(CLK_speed, stat_buf + 1, strlen(stat_buf));
        s++;
      }
      else if (stat_buf[0] == 'D') {
        strncpy(RAM_usage, stat_buf + 1, strlen(stat_buf));
        s++;
      }
      else if (stat_buf[0] == 'E') {
        strncpy(IP_addr, stat_buf + 1, strlen(stat_buf));
        s++;
      }
    }

    // Clear Values
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 17);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, prev_SD_usage);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 42);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, prev_CPU_temp);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 67);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, prev_CLK_speed);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 92);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, prev_RAM_usage);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 117);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(0, 0, 0), small_font, prev_IP_addr);

    strncpy(prev_SD_usage, SD_usage, strlen(SD_usage));
    strncpy(prev_CPU_temp, CPU_temp, strlen(CPU_temp));
    strncpy(prev_CLK_speed, CLK_speed, strlen(CLK_speed));
    strncpy(prev_RAM_usage, RAM_usage, strlen(RAM_usage));
    strncpy(prev_IP_addr, IP_addr, strlen(IP_addr));

    // Display Values
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 5);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r, g, b), small_font, "SD Usage");
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 17);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r1, g1, b1), small_font, SD_usage);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 30);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r, g, b), small_font, "SoC Temp");
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 42);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r1, g1, b1), small_font, CPU_temp);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 55);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r, g, b), small_font, "Clock Speed");
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 67);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r1, g1, b1), small_font, CLK_speed);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 80);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r, g, b), small_font, "RAM Usage");
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 92);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r1, g1, b1), small_font, RAM_usage);
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 105);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r, g, b), small_font, "IP Address");
    SSD1351_set_cursor(5, 117);
    SSD1351_printf(SSD1351_get_rgb(r1, g1, b1), small_font, IP_addr);

    SSD1351_update();
    sleep_ms(5000);
  }  
}

bool receive_start_string() {
  char start_str[] = "START\n";
  int start_str_index = 0;
  int data;

  while (start_str_index < strlen(start_str)) {
      data = getchar();
      if (data == start_str[start_str_index]) {
          start_str_index++;
      } else {
          start_str_index = 0;
      }
  }
  return start_str_index == strlen(start_str);
}

bool receive_end_string() {
  char end_str[] = "END\n";
  int end_str_index = 0;
  int data;

  while (end_str_index < strlen(end_str)) {
      data = getchar();
      if (data == end_str[end_str_index]) {
          end_str_index++;
      } else {
          end_str_index = 0;
      }
  }
  return end_str_index == strlen(end_str);
}

bool receive_stop_string() {
  char stop_str[] = "X\n";
  int stop_str_index = 0;
  int data;

  while (stop_str_index < strlen(stop_str)) {
      data = getchar();
      if (data == stop_str[stop_str_index]) {
          stop_str_index++;
      } else {
          stop_str_index = 0;
      }
  }
  return stop_str_index == strlen(stop_str);
}

void serial_thread(void) {
  // Check if there's any serial input available
  if (stdin && !feof(stdin)) {
    while(1){

      // Check if the string is 'X'
      if (receive_stop_string()) {
          multicore_reset_core1();
          sleep_ms(10);
          thread_running = true;
          multicore_launch_core1(display_stats);
      }

      // Check if the string is 'START'
      if (receive_start_string()) {
          thread_running = false;
          multicore_reset_core1();
          SSD1351_clear_8();
          SSD1351_write_image(); 
          SSD1351_update();
      }
      
      // Check if the string is 'END'
      if (receive_end_string()) {
          SSD1351_clear_8();
          SSD1351_update();
          thread_running = true;
          multicore_launch_core1(display_stats);
      }
    }
  }    
}

int main(void){

  // GPIO Set-Up
  spi_set_format(SPI_PORT, 8, SPI_CPOL_1, SPI_CPHA_1, SPI_MSB_FIRST);
  gpio_init(CS);
  gpio_set_dir(CS, GPIO_OUT);
  gpio_put(CS, 1);
  gpio_set_function (SCK, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
  gpio_set_function (MOSI, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
  gpio_pull_up(SCK);
  gpio_pull_up(MOSI);
  gpio_init(DC);
  gpio_set_dir(DC,GPIO_OUT);
  gpio_init(RST);
  gpio_set_dir(RST,GPIO_OUT);

  // SPI Initialisation
  stdio_init_all(); 
  spi_init(SPI_PORT, 15000000);
  SSD1351_init();  

  // Set up the video thread
  multicore_launch_core1(play_splash_vid);
  
  while(1) {
    serial_thread();
  }

return 0;
}
```

**Pico Driver - SSD1351 (SSD1351.c)**

```cpp
#include "ssd1351.h"

/* Buffer to hold the Display RAM Data */
static DRAM displayRAM;

#define DRAM_16 displayRAM.halfw
#define DRAM_8 displayRAM.byte

uint8_t buffer[OLED_BUF_SIZE] = {0x00};

// Screen cursor for printing
struct cursor{
  uint8_t x;
  uint8_t y;
}SSD1351_cursor;

void SSD1351_SendByte(uint8_t data){
  spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, &data, 1);
}

void SSD1351_SendBuffer(uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t len){
  spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, buffer, len);
}

void SSD1351_write_command(uint8_t cmd){
  gpio_put(DC, 0);
  gpio_put(CS, 0);
  SSD1351_SendByte(cmd);
  gpio_put(CS, 1);
}

void SSD1351_write_data(uint8_t data){
  gpio_put(DC, 1);
  gpio_put(CS, 0);
  SSD1351_SendByte(data);
  gpio_put(CS, 1);
}

void SSD1351_write_data_buffer(uint8_t *data, uint16_t len){
  gpio_put(DC, 1);
  gpio_put(CS, 0);
  SSD1351_SendBuffer(data, len);
  gpio_put(CS, 1);
}

void SSD1351_update(void){
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETCOLUMN);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x7F);
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETROW);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x7F);
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  SSD1351_write_data_buffer(DRAM_8, DRAM_SIZE_8);
}

void SSD1351_init(void){
  gpio_put(DC, 1);
  gpio_put(RST, 1);
  sleep_ms(10);
  gpio_put(RST, 0);
  sleep_ms(500);
  gpio_put(RST, 1);
  gpio_put(DC, 0);
  sleep_ms(50);
 
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_COMMANDLOCK);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x12);
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_COMMANDLOCK);
  SSD1351_write_data(0xB1);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_DISPLAYOFF);
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_CLOCKDIV);
  SSD1351_write_data(0xF1);
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_MUXRATIO);
  SSD1351_write_data(127);
  sleep_ms(600);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETREMAP);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x74);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETCOLUMN);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x7F);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETROW);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x7F);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_STARTLINE);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_DISPLAYOFFSET);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETGPIO);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x00);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_FUNCTIONSELECT);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x01);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_PRECHARGE);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x32);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_VCOMH);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x05);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_NORMALDISPLAY);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_CONTRASTABC);
  SSD1351_write_data(0xC8);                          // Color A: Blue
  SSD1351_write_data(0x80);                          // Color B: Green
  SSD1351_write_data(0xC8);                          // Color C: Red

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_CONTRASTMASTER);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x0F);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_SETVSL);
  SSD1351_write_data(0xA0);
  SSD1351_write_data(0xB5);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x55);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_PRECHARGE2);
  SSD1351_write_data(0x01);

  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_DISPLAYON);

  sleep_ms(10);
}

void SSD1351_clear(void){
  memset(DRAM_16, 0, DRAM_SIZE_16);
}

void SSD1351_clear_8(void){
  memset(DRAM_8, 0, DRAM_SIZE_8);
}

void SSD1351_fill(uint16_t color){
  for (int i = 0; i < DRAM_SIZE_16; i++){
    DRAM_16[i] = color;
  }
}

/*
 * @brief Converts from RGB to a single 16bit value
 * @param r: starting x coordinate
 * @para g: starting y coordinate
 * @param b: width of the rectangle
 * @reval 16bit value with the rgb color for display
 */
uint16_t SSD1351_get_rgb(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b){
  uint16_t rgb_color = 0;
  rgb_color |= ((r/8) << 8);
  rgb_color |= ((g/4) >> 3);
  rgb_color |= (((g/4) % 0x07) << 13);
  rgb_color |= ((b/8) << 3);
  return rgb_color;
}

/**
 * @brief Writes a pixel data to the screen RAM buffer
 * @param color: Unsigned int16 containing color code
 * @param x: Pixel's horizontal position
 * @param y: Pixel's vertical position
 * @retval None
 */
void SSD1351_write_pixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color){
  if ( x > 127 || y > 127 || x < 0 || y < 0){
    return;
  }
  int a = (x - 127) + (y * 128);
  DRAM_16[a] = color;
}

static void SSD1351_write_char(uint16_t color, font_t font, char c){
  uint16_t fd;
  if ((COLUMNS <= SSD1351_cursor.x + font.width) || (ROWS <= SSD1351_cursor.y + font.height)){
    return;
  }
  if (c == '\n'){
    SSD1351_cursor.x = 127;
  }
  else{
    for (int i = 0; i < font.height; i++){
        fd = font.data[(c - 32) * font.height + i];
        for (int j = 0; j < font.width; j++){
          if ((fd << j) & 0x8000){
            SSD1351_write_pixel(SSD1351_cursor.x + j, SSD1351_cursor.y + i, color);
          }
        }
      }
  }
  SSD1351_cursor.x += font.width;
  if ((SSD1351_cursor.x + font.width >= 127) & (SSD1351_cursor.y + font.height <= 127)){
    SSD1351_cursor.y = SSD1351_cursor.y + font.height + 2;
    SSD1351_cursor.x = 0;
  }
  return;
}

static void SSD1351_write_string(uint16_t color, font_t font, char *line){
  if (line == NULL){
    return;
  }
  while (*line != 0){
    SSD1351_write_char(color, font, *line);
    line++;
  }
}

static void SSD1351_write_int(uint16_t color, font_t font, int8_t n){
  char number[5];
  sprintf(number, "%i", n);
  SSD1351_write_string(color, font, number);
}

/*
 * @brief Prints a formatted string to the display
 * @param color: unsigned integer for the color of the string
 * @param font: structure holding the type of font
 * @param format: formatted string
 */
void SSD1351_printf(uint16_t color, font_t font, const char *format, ...){
  if (format == NULL){
    return;
  }
  va_list valist;
  va_start(valist, format);
  while (*format != 0){
    if (*format != '%'){
      SSD1351_write_char(color, font, *format);
      format++;
    }
    else{
      format++;
      switch(*format){
        case 's':
          SSD1351_write_string(color, font, va_arg(valist, char *));
          break;
        case 'c':
          SSD1351_write_char(color, font, va_arg(valist, int)); //?
          break;
        case 'i':
          SSD1351_write_int(color, font, (int8_t)va_arg(valist, int));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      format++;
    }
  }
}

void SSD1351_set_cursor(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
  SSD1351_cursor.x = x;
  SSD1351_cursor.y = y;
}

// void SSD1351_write_image(void){
//   int i = 0;
//   while (i < DRAM_SIZE_8) {
//     int data = getchar_timeout_us(100000);
//     if (data != PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
//         DRAM_8[i++] = (uint8_t)data;
//     }
//   }
// }


void SSD1351_write_image(void){
  SSD1351_clear();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < DRAM_SIZE_8) {
    int data = getchar_timeout_us(0);
    if (data != PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
        buffer[i++] = (uint8_t)data;
    }
  }
  sleep_ms(100);
  memcpy(DRAM_8, buffer, DRAM_SIZE_8);
}
```

**(Python Script - get_image.py)**

```python
Purpose: Converts a PNG image to an RGB565 before sending the data to the Pico from the Pi 4. 
#!/usr/bin/python3

from lib2to3.pgen2 import pgen
from operator import truediv
from pickle import TRUE
import subprocess
import serial
from serial import tools
from serial.tools import list_ports
import sys
import time
import os
import struct
import linecache
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils
import cv2
import psutil
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def pico_com_port():
    global pico_port
    picoVID = "2E8A" # Pico USB Vendor ID
    picoPID = "000A" # Pico USB product ID
    port_list = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

    for device in port_list:
        if (device.vid != None or device.pid != None):
            if ('{:04X}'.format(device.vid) == picoVID and
                '{:04X}'.format(device.pid) == picoPID):
                pico_port = device.device
                break
            pico_port = None
            print("Raspberry Pi Pico failed to open serial port. Please check VID and PID IDs are correct.")

def get_img_directories():
    global wheel, screenshot, boxart
    tempFile = open('/tmp/retropie-oled.log', 'r', -1)    # , "utf-8")
    retropie_oled_img_dir = tempFile.readlines()
    tempFile.close()
    screenshot = retropie_oled_img_dir[0].rstrip('\n')
    wheel = retropie_oled_img_dir[1].rstrip('\n')
    boxart = retropie_oled_img_dir[2].rstrip('\n')

def center_crop(img,dim):
    width, height = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
    crop_width = dim[0] if dim[0]<img.shape[1] else img.shape[1]
    crop_height = dim[1] if dim[1]<img.shape[0] else img.shape[0]
    start_x = (width - crop_width) // 2
    start_y = (height - crop_height) // 2
    return img[start_y:start_y+crop_height, start_x:start_x+crop_width]

GAME_START_FILE = '/dev/shm/runcommand.info'

while True:
    # Wait for game launch event file to be created
    while not os.path.exists(GAME_START_FILE):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    while not os.path.exists('/tmp/retropie-oled.log'):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    get_img_directories()
    img = cv2.imread(screenshot, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img2 = cv2.imread(wheel, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    if img.shape[1] > img.shape[0]:
        r = 128.0 / img.shape[0]
        dim = (int(img.shape[1] * r), 128)
    elif img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
        r = 128.0 / img.shape[1]
        dim = (128, int(img.shape[0] * r))
    else:
        dim = (128,128)

    img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 128, 128 ,128, 128, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0,0,0,0])
    img = center_crop(img, (128,128))

    r = 128.0 / img2.shape[1]
    dim = (128, int(img2.shape[0] * r))

    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img2, 128, 128 ,128, 128, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0,0,0,0])
    img2 = center_crop(img2, (128,128))

    cv2.imwrite('screenshot_scaled.png', img)
    cv2.imwrite('wheel_scaled.png', img2)

    background = Image.fromarray(img)
    foreground = Image.fromarray(img2)

    background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
    output = background.save('combined.png')

    len_argument = len(sys.argv)
    filesize = 0
    if (len_argument != 3):
        print("")
        print("Correct Usage:")
        print ("\tpython get_image.py <pngfile> <binary_file>")
        print ("")
        sys.exit(0)

    try:
        im=Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    except:
        print("Failed to open png file ", sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(0)

    image_height = im.size[1]
    image_width = im.size[0]

    try:
        binoutfile = open(sys.argv[2],"wb")
    except:
        print ("Can't write the binary file %s" % sys.argv[2])
        sys.exit(0)

    pix = im.load()
    for h in range(image_height):
        for w in range(image_width):
            if w < im.size[0]:
                R=pix[w,h][0]>>3
                G=pix[w,h][1]>>2
                B=pix[w,h][2]>>3

                rgb = (R<<11) | (G<<5) | B

                binoutfile.write(struct.pack('H', rgb))
            else:
                rgb = 0

    binoutfile.close()

    pico_com_port()


    ser = serial.Serial(pico_port, 921600)
    ser.write(b"S\n")
    ser.write(b"START\n")
    data = open("out.bin", "rb")
    ser.write(data.read())
    print("Image sent")
    data.close()
    ser.close()

    # Remove the game start file
    os.remove(GAME_START_FILE)
    time.sleep(5)
    break
```

**(Python Script - get_statistics.py)**

```python
import serial
import os
import time
import sys
import psutil
import socket
import subprocess
from serial.tools import list_ports

def get_pico_port():
    picoVID = "2E8A" # Pico USB Vendor ID
    picoPID = "000A" # Pico USB product ID
    port_list = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

    for device in port_list:
        if (device.vid != None or device.pid != None):
            if ('{:04X}'.format(device.vid) == picoVID and
                '{:04X}'.format(device.pid) == picoPID):
                return device.device

    return None

def wait_for_connection():
    # Loop until serial connection is established
    connection = None
    while connection is None:
        connection = get_pico_port()
        if connection is None:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Pico not connected")

def check_connection(port):
    if port is None:
        return False
    return os.path.exists(port)


# Set the process name to check emulation station
process_name = "emulationstation"

# Status of splash video
vid_stopped = False

while True:
    get_pico_port()
    wait_for_connection()
    
    pico_port = get_pico_port()
    connected = check_connection(pico_port)
    
    if connected:
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(pico_port, 115200)

            while True:
                # Check if Emulation Station is running
                for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
                    if proc.info['name'] == process_name:
                        # Send a command to stop the video
                        ser.write(b"X\n")
                        vid_stopped = True
                        break
                if vid_stopped:
                    break

                # Wait before checking again
                time.sleep(1)

            # SD Usage
            sd_stat = os.statvfs("/")
            total = sd_stat.f_frsize * sd_stat.f_blocks / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            used = (sd_stat.f_frsize * (sd_stat.f_blocks - sd_stat.f_bfree)) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            disk_data = "{:.0f}/{:.0f}GB\n".format(used, total)

            # CPU Temperature
            with open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp', 'r') as temp_file:
                temp = temp_file.readline()
                temp = float(temp.strip()) / 1000
            temp = "{:.1f}C\n".format(temp)

            # Clock Speed
            with open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq", "r") as clock_file:
                clock_speed = float(clock_file.read().strip()) / 1000
            clock_speed_data = "{:.0f}MHz\n".format(clock_speed)

            # RAM Usage
            mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
            total_ram = mem.total / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            used_ram = mem.used / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            ram_data = "{:.1f}/{:.1f}GB\n".format(used_ram, total_ram)

            # IP Address
            host_name = os.popen("hostname -I").read()
            ip_address = host_name

            ser.write(b"A" + disk_data.encode('utf-8'))
            ser.write(b"B" + temp.encode('utf-8'))
            ser.write(b"C" + clock_speed_data.encode('utf-8'))
            ser.write(b"D" + ram_data.encode('utf-8'))
            ser.write(b"E" + ip_address.encode('utf-8'))

        except serial.SerialException:
            print("Pico Disconnected")
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated to help me get my project working!
Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you include a schematic of your setup? It’s not obvious what components are present or how they are connected. Also you talk a lot of statistics but it’s quite unclear what you are talking about and whether this is significant or not. Finally, did you use a logic analyser the check what is sent on the wire on all the relevant interfaces?

Comment: Hi @jcaron. Not sure why the schematic here is relevant however I am driving the display over SPI. I've managed to get the statistics working and the screen initialized. This is more of a software question than hardware. By statistics, I mean I am sending data from the Pi 4 to the Pico over serial via the get_statistics.py script, which I have now attached above. I'm reading this data into a buffer to display on the OLED, and then when "START\n" is sent, I am trying to display an image on the OLED.

Comment: It’s slightly clearer now, but for someone who stumbles on this post, even a high-level schematic showing the Pi, the Pico and the screen would help. Also, can you include examples of what you should be displaying and what is actually shown? That would help a lot to determine where to look, you have quite a bit of code in that question, and we have very little idea of what we are looking for.

Comment: @jcaron
The first thing that is shown is a splashscreen, which displays until the process "emulationstation" begins. After that, stats are displayed on the screen. When I start a game, I'm wanting to stop the stats and then switch over to a combined image of the game being played, which is read in over serial via the getchar_timeout_us() function within SSD1351_write_image() function. 

1) Splashscreen: https://imgur.com/HhMHOhG
2) Stats: https://imgur.com/a/67Sub3V
3) Image (currently corrupted): https://imgur.com/a/2R3yqso
4) Image (should look like): https://imgur.com/c8BJ36k

Comment: @jcaron Hope that helps explain things a bit better.